# Where to report scammer Ether wallet addresses?

Tags: wallets, public-key, privacy

[Bitcoinabuse.com](http://Bitcoinabuse.com) is where we can report scammer addresses for Bitcoin wallets. What is the equivalent for Ether scammer addresses?

Answer (score 1):

It used to be the case that you could submit addresses to [MyCrypto](https://github.com/MyCryptoHQ/MyCrypto) (and a couple of other blacklisting services) which would then be used by the [EtherAddressLookup](https://harrydenley.com/ethaddresslookup-chrome-extension-release/) Chrome extension to warn you when those addresses were present on a given webpage.

I'm unsure if this facility is still in place.

Two problems with this:

1. Scammers can create new addresses far more quickly than they can be reported and blacklisted, so you're fighting a losing battle. (*Unless you're doing some sort of clever automated chain analysis.)
2. It's not always clear that an address is malicious. Who makes the call, and what are the qualifying criteria? Further, submitting addresses as malicious can be used as a griefing attack on valid, non-malicious addresses.

A better solution is to cultivate a system of good personal security hygiene.

---

*Which is exactly what Etherscan (and probably other services) do. -> https://info.etherscan.com/ethprotect/

Comment: the idea is not to protect oneself, but to track down and apprehend perpetrators

Answer (score 1):

My company has built a new product called ScanBlocks ( https://ScanBlocks.io ) which allows you to search and report addresses.

None of these blacklisting services will be perfect, but we are building a large dataset of blockchain addresses of malicious actors that can be used for future traceability, crypto service providers, the public, and by law enforcement.

With our tool it allows for a reason for report as well, therefore alerting the next user that searches the address to view the reason why - i.e. then we can get some differentiation between NFT disputes versus scammers, ransomware, etc.

Comment: Traced a wallet funneling embezzled funds to a wallet on a centralized exchange using the peel-chain strategy. How to ask the exchange (Binance) to freeze or investigate that account? It's holding thousands of stolen bitcoin

Answer (score 1):

You can report malicious or suspicious crypto-addresses at DirtyHash (https://dirtyhash.com). DirtyHash applies machine learning techniques to detect malicious wallet addresses in realtime, and provides a risk score for a particular address. In addition DirtyHash scrapes the internet for malicious entities, uses publicly available crypto scam databases, leverages reports submitted by users, maintains blacklists of malicious entities, and whitelists of known entities. DirtyHash also searches for malicious entities as reported in the sanctions list by many law enforcement agencies.

Comment: Traced a wallet funneling embezzled funds to a wallet on a centralized exchange using the peel-chain strategy. How to ask the exchange (Binance) to freeze or investigate that account? It's holding thousands of stolen bitcoin